# I did X, Y, which Z vs. I did X, Y, that Z

Tags: word-choice, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I am familiar with the basic [distinction](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/which-versus-that-0) between *that vs. which.* (e.g. "Gems that sparkle often elicit forgiveness." vs. "Diamonds, which are expensive, often elicit forgiveness.")

Is it correct to say "I did X, Y, **that** Z", provided that Z restrict the kind of X I am talking about?

Example:

> I developed an algorithm, Algorthmixv1, **that** improves Algorthmixv2.

Comment: Now I see what you're asking!  Is it OK to use commas with "that" even though you normally use them with "which"?  Yes, in your example, BECAUSE the commas are setting off an appositive (algorithmixv1 is an appositive of "algorithm"). This has nothing to do with the comma-before-which/no-comma-before-that rule.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, if you made that into an answer, I would upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is confusing, particularly since you gave both algorithms the same name, which means you are saying an algorithm improves ITS OWN efficiency. An impossibility currently (although possibly a valuable trait for true Artificial Intelligence in the distant future). I see the problem you are posing, namely: 1) does using an appositive sufficiently restrict the meaning of the first noun that it would then require "which", or 2) can one treat the noun-and-appositive as a unit that is being restricted by the subsequent phrase only, so you use "that"?  My inclination is the former, but I have no source to back that up.

Comment: Whoops, it's a typo! The first Algorthmixv2 was meant to be Algorthmixv1.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the example confuses the issue. It's grammatically irrelevant to introduce the element **Y** into *I did X, Y, which Z*, since its only purpose is to represent, restate, or expand upon **X**. And OP's example element **Z** is distractingly long for something which can just be a simple intransitive verb...

> I relaxed, which helped

The only thing that matters is **Z** (my *"helped"*, OP's *"improves Algorthmixv2's run time by a factor of 2"* is a [non-restrictive relative clause](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/103103whichthat.htm), so it's introduced by ***which***. From that getitwriteonline.com link...

> *The rule of thumb, then, is that **which** clauses are nonrestrictive (nonessential) while **that** clauses are restrictive (essential).*